# Is there a keyboard shortcut to bring up Finder?

Tags: macos, keyboard

Is there a default keyboard shortcut to start a new Finder window?
If not, is there a way to assign one?

I tried System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts and created a new item for Finder, and assigned <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>, among other things, but nothing worked.

Comment: Commenting because I don't have the reputation to answer this question: +a will focus the finder icon in the dock, after which you can press <Enter> to open it. So +a <Enter>.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By default, no, there's no keyboard shortcut to activate Finder.

[**Keyboard Maestro**](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) can do this though:

[image: When ⇧⌘F, activate Finder]

Answer (score 185):

It's actually easy. On Yosemite, just press <kbd>option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd>. That will open a new Smart Finder window. You then can navigate from there. It works on a system level no matter what application you're running.

No need for scripts or complicated setups.

Turn this option on in System Preferences > keyboard > shortcuts > spotlight > "show finder search window" in recent versions. This can be mapped to other keys too, but it can cause conflicts in other apps that might be using your desired shortcut.

Comment: @kmarsh After Search This Mac comes up you can press `command`+`shift`+`G` to type in the path you want to go to.

Comment: Now on the latest release, Command+F brings up Finder in file mode (not Search this Mac) again, just like the old days.

Comment: From what I understand the edit explained how to enable your solution on recent macOS versions where it isn‘t enabled by default.

Comment: @kmarsh not working for me on Big Sur.

Comment: @kmarsh and Jaime Hablutzel, that only works if focus is already on Finder

Answer (score 27):

1. Open [Automator](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2488) and choose the service template.
2. Change the input type from selected text to no input.
3. Add a Launch Application action and drop Finder on the pop-up button from /System/Library/CoreServices/. (The dialog for choosing an application does not allow selecting Finder.)
4. Save the service and give it a shortcut in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services.

The service only opens a new window if there is no existing Finder window. To open a new window every time, add a Get Specified Finder Items action, drop the folder you want to open on the list, and then add a Reveal Finder Items action.

---

Automator is included in OS X: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14303 (Mavericks), http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11360 (Mountain Lion), etc.

Background: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automator_(software)

Further reading if you're interested in doing more with Automator: http://www.macosxautomation.com/automator/

Comment: This really good but the Keyboard Maestro answer allows you to specify many more options; for example, if you press the shortcut key again, it toggles back to the prior front application

Comment: I used your advice, but made some changes as your method made 2 windows pop up, and the folder did not open. I use 2 actions: Get Specified Finder Items->Open Finder Items. Thanks for the info!

Comment: finder is greyes in system servics, can't add it, catalina 15

Answer (score 22):

You can always use this trick to open Finder..

```
alt + command + <space>
```

This is actually a shortcut to search for files IN FINDER MODE, In other words it opens Finder directly without needing to install any tools.

You can add your favorite directory onto the sidebar (Finder > System Preferences > Sidebar) and access it easily.

Comment: Great buddy. This is what I was exactly looking for

Comment: The menu appears to me as Finder > Preferences > Sidebar, and the choices there do not affect the mostly blank Search window that appears with that key sequence. However CMD + Shift + F works (for me) to get the Finder file browser window.

Comment: `alt` might be a windows key, in mac it is `option`.

Comment: did it quit working in os 12.5 (monterey)? or did i mess up a setting? !@$%^#

Answer (score 19):

Actually I find it easy to bring up the finder with COMMAND-TAB. Cycle thru the open applications till you have selected Finder.

If any windows are already open but hidden they pop to the front if none are open a simple COMMAND-N opens a new window.

Not exactly a simple WINDOWS-E but it does work.

Comment: I guess if you don't have too many windows open, that would be fine. I just missed the old Windows-E so I now programmed F6 using Keyboard Maestro

Comment: Thanks! Never knew why so the Finder is always shown in Command Tab but didn't open. Now I've realized it's been closed, but only their instances, like when you close a browser with Command Shift W, instead of Command Q. Indeed you can't completely close it (Command Q won't work). So it makes sense you can use `Command N` to open a new instance as you'd do with any other app (any browser, Word, any...).

Answer (score 10):

There is a few native keyboard shortcuts to open a new Finder window:

- <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>: Computer folder
- <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>: Desktop folder
- <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>: Home folder
- <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>: Documents folder
- <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>: Applications folder
- <kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>: Downloads folder

Note that the active app has priority over global shortcuts, so you might want to click on your desktop before trying those.

Comment: As @Creaforge says, they won't work "directly", i.e. regardless of where you are. But press first   `⌥` + `⌘` + `Space`, as said by others, and you are done; you can now use any of these other shortcuts to specifically go to any of the corresponding folders.

Comment: Also, `Shift Alt L` doesn't work, the right one for Downloads is `Option Command L`

Answer (score 9):

If you have the Powerpack for Alfred 2, you can create a workflow like this:

[image]

Hotkeys have a short delay by default, but you can reduce it by changing the trigger behavior:

[image]

Another option is to use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <vkopenurldef>
    <name>KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_FINDER</name>
    <url>file:///System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app</url>
  </vkopenurldef>
  <item>
    <name>shortcuts</name>
    <identifier>shortcuts</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F12, ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_FINDER</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use [TotalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com) there is a nice 'visor' feature which causes a Finder window to slide up from the bottom of the screen. The sliding in or out can be linked to a hot key combo (double press option works well for me) and then it is always easy to do a bit if quick Finder manipulation.

Comment: Just bought total finder. It's pretty nice, thanks

Comment: Do you know any alternative since TotalFinder will soon be ended ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to open Finder with your home folder then open Spotlight, type `~` (tilda) or your user name, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you want to open Finder with a specific file or folder:

1. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to show **Spotlight** and start typing the name of the file/folder you want.
2. Use the <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> to highlight the file or folder, and then press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> — you'll get a Finder window with the given folder or file.

> Hint: While an item is selected in Spotlight you can press <kbd>⌘</kbd> to have the path displayed in the status line.
>
> Hint: To configure what Spotlight should search type <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (*Command+comma*) while the Spotlight search bar is open.

Comment: Good thing about this option is that it bring the already opened Finder if you already had it open with one of these searched folders. If you just want to get the finder, you can just write the first words (like `find`) in spotlight

Answer (score 2):

I also had this question too and was hoping that one of these solutions that didn't require 3rd party software I would be happy with but unfortunately the OPTION + CMD + SPACE doesn't cut it for me because it opens a blank Finder window every time. And I couldn't figure out the instructions to get an Automator script to launch Finder.

I even tried using an Apple script action in Automator but they just didn't work the way I wanted.

However I did find a SUPER simple app on the Mac App store that behaves exactly the way I wanted so I thought I would share. 
NOTE: you do need to create a manual shortcut for Finder as this app doesn't count Finder as the first app in your dock. But the thing I like most is a second press of the shortcut will hide the app too. Simple and beautiful.

Snap. https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/snap/id418073146?mt=12

(And lolz at the person who wrote a 1 star review about clicking their fingers hoping this app would do something. trolololol!)

Answer (score 2):

Without any special tools you can simply use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> and while you cycle through the apps highlight the Finder and hold <kbd>option ⌥</kbd>, then let go of <kbd>⌘</kbd>. A new Finder window will open with whatever folder is set in the **Finder preferences** > **New Finder windows show** option.

Comment: I'm surprised this shortcut didn't come up til today

Comment: It needs to be the Left `Option`

Answer (score 2):

Using [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/), it's possible to send Shortcuts directly to apps:

1. Open BTT.
2. Go to **Keyboard Shortcuts** triggers.
3. Create a new Keyboard Shortcut, I use ⌃E as it's the remapped Windows-Key on my Logitech G915 TKL Lightspeed Tactile, using the Karabiner-Elements-app. This way I get the same experience on both OS.
4. Add a **Action** and choose **Send Shortcut to Specific App**.
5. **Record Shortcut** is the Shortcut to send to finder, in this case **⌘N** for a **New Finder Window**.
6. In the **Send to App** section, find Finder at /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app
7. Check ✅ **Bring app to front before sending**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> configured to summon Finder window:

[image]

Settings => Keyboard => Shortcuts => Show Finder search window: change to<kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Please go to System preferences > Keyboad > Shortcut tab.

On the left pane, select Services, and make sure spotlight is selected. It is by default COMMAND + SPACE + F. You may change id if you wish.

[image: COMMAND + SPACE + F]

Comment: Only works if you are in the Desktop (if you click on the desktop)

Answer (score 0):

The default keyboard shortcut to open a new Finder window is <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, but it works only when Finder is in focus, which I assume, is not the way you want it to work. I guess you want to be able to open it no matter which application is in focus right now.

To do that we have two ways: standard and non-standard with help of a third-party app [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/).

**Standard way** described by [netrox](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37536/netrox) [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/163790/397227). And I used to use it for a couple of years. But the problem is that it creates a *New Smart Folder* window every time, instead of bringing some opened one.

So I found **non-standard** which works exactly as I wanted it to (Bring Finder window in the focus or create a new one if there are no windows opened):
You need to create a new trigger there, assign desired shortcut for it, and choose "Open Finder" as an action.
[image: open Finder with BTT]

Answer (score 0):

Using [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/), the following rule maps <kbd>left_control</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to open Finder:

```json
{
  "description": "Open Finder",
  "manipulators": [
    {
      "from": {
        "key_code": "f",
        "modifiers": {
          "mandatory": ["left_control"]
        }
      },
      "to": [
        {
          "shell_command": "open -a Finder"
        }
      ],
      "type": "basic"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this whilst trying to find a macOS equivalent for the <kbd>Super/Windows-E</kbd> shortcut on Windows that opens a Windows Explorer window. I thought it would be useful to summarise into a single answer.

Unfortunately there is no quick single-command comparable equivalent in macOS (accurate as of Sanoma *14.2.1*). The following are the best options I could find:

1. <kbd>Cmd-Tab</kbd> (may be required multiple times) to select the Finder application
2. <kbd>Cmd-N</kbd> to open a new Finder window

(this is easier to remember and more ergonomic on a QWERTY keyboard but may require repetition of the first step)

1. <kbd>Opt-Cmd-Space</kbd> to open a Finder window in *Searching this Mac* mode
2. <kbd>Shift-Cmd-H</kbd> to navigate to home directory within Finder (other shortcuts, e.g. <kbd>Shift-Cmd-A</kbd> for applications, can be seen within the *Go* Finder menu)

More information on macOS default shortcuts is available on the [Apple website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236).

Answer (score -3):

Pres the the following keys combination 
Command+Shift+F

Comment: This is now the correct answer.

Comment: This is not correct at all; it just engages full screen mode on macOS Catalina.

Comment: This only works when Finder is the in-focus application. Otherwise, it full-screens the current application. So you need to press command-tab or option-command-space first

Answer (score -4):

Here is the answer.

Press **'command + shift + ~'** ,then you will have a surprise.