# Can I add folder keyboard shortcuts? (like there are for Home, Downloads, etc)

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder, folders, shortcut

Finder's Go menu shows a bunch of keyboard shortcuts for many standard folders:

[image: screenshot]

So within Finder, but also within the Open or Save File dialogs of other applications, I can use <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to go to my `Documents` folder, or <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for my `Downloads` folder, et cetera.

I happily use this hundreds of times a day.

Can I add my own keyboard shortcuts here? For example, as a Developer, I often find myself going to my `~/Code` folder by pressing <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for `Home`, then navigating to `Code`. But I'd rather press something like <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to go there directly.

Is this possible, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible. To look at how, please read [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114935/197118) – it's better than I could have explained.

Specifically, you would want to try what's written under the steps:

> To open a new window every time, add a Get Specified Finder Items action, drop the folder you want to open on the list, and then add a Reveal Finder Items action.

So in Automator you would add your folder as described above, and then carry out step 4, assigning whichever shortcut you wanted for it.