# Mac Keyboard Shortcut to Bring Up Finder

Tags: mac, finder, mojave, shortcut

How can you create a keyboard shortcut to bring up the Finder, as if you had clicked on the Finder on the Dock?

Answer (score 3):

1. Launch **Automator** (in Utilities)
2. Menu: File -> **New Window**
3. Choose: **Quick Action**<sup>*</sup>
4. Worflow receives: **no input**
5. In **Utilities** on left, double click: **Run Shell Script**
6. Shell: **/bin/zsh**
7. Enter for the shell command: **open -a Finder**
8. **Save** the service with whatever name you want
9. In **System Preferences**, click on **Keyboard**
10. Click on **Shortcuts** at the top and then on **Services** at the left
11. On the right part of the window, scroll down to **General**
12. Find the service that you just saved, make sure it is checked, and **set a unique hotkey** for it
13. **Quit** the System Preferences

Enjoy your new hotkey to bring up the Finder.

<sup>* In versions of macOS before macOS Mojave, the option was called **Service**.</sup>

Comment: The other option, of course, was just to cycle through CMD + TAB to select the Finder.

Answer (score 0):

[Source:](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114933/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-bring-up-finder)

> 1. Open [Automator](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114933/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-bring-up-finder) and choose the service template.
> 2. Change the input type from selected text to no input.
> 3. Add a Launch Application action and drop Finder on the pop-up button from /System/Library/CoreServices/. (The dialog for choosing an application does not allow selecting Finder.)
> 4. Save the service and give it a shortcut in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services.
>
> The service only opens a new window if there is no existing Finder window. To open a new window every time, add a Get Specified Finder Items action, drop the folder you want to open on the list, and then add a Reveal Finder Items action.
>
> ---
>
> Automator is included in OS X: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14303 (Mavericks), http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11360 (Mountain Lion), etc.
>
> Background: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automator_(software)
>
> Further reading if you're interested in doing more with Automator: http://www.macosxautomation.com/automator/

or:

> It's actually easy. Just press <kbd>option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd>. That will open a new Smart Finder window. You then can navigate from there. It works on a system level no matter what application you're running.
>
> No need for scripts or complicated setups.

In the future please search for the topic before creating a post :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to search for existing solutions. In case of questions which have gotten asked before it is usually better to flag the question for mod attention (or vote to close as a duplicate once you have enough reputation) than to duplicate answers though.