# Map Command-E to summon Finder file manager

Tags: high-sierra

OSX: Is there a procedure to configure Command-E to invoke the Finder file manager?  It would be nice if it were to open a new instance of finder, regardless if there is an instance open. Unfortunately, a Google search of said keywords in the title have not produced a viable solution.   This key sequence was chosen because I already have it ingrained from using Windows to invoke Command-E to summon a file manager.

Preferred solutions make use of existing OSX functionality and do not require purchase of applications.

This question is significantly more constrained than [Is there a keyboard shortcut to bring up Finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114933/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-bring-up-finder/396854#396854) in the sense, the current questions is confined to Command-E and not any other hotkey.  It would be nice if the moderators could unlock this post and I can move / add my solution to this question for the community.

Comment: @ankii please post your answer to the original question

Comment: @nohillside https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/163790/313842 Just cleanup the comments too, I'd say.

Comment: Solution: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/396854/187540